# Laravel - Press back button takes me to unexpected page after update method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

So I am creating an application that manages users with the CRUD operations using `Route::resource`.
I have the following pages:

- index page (get) - which shows the list of users. Within each user row there are two buttons that links to the edit() method and show() method.
- edit page (get) - which shows the form with pre loaded saved data so that the can edit from there.
- show page (get) - which displays the users's information
- update (put) - which saves all the fields provided by the user to the database.

After when the I update, I want to redirect to the index page (which shows the list of users)

```
if($user->save()){ 
    Session::flash('usersaved', 'The user: '.Input::get('user_name'). ' was saved');
    return Redirect::route('admin.users.index');
}
```

The redirect back to the index works correctly with the message BUT, right after I press the link that goes the to `show()` method (only on the edited client) and then press the back button on the browser (Google Chrome), it takes me to the `edit()` method not the `index()` method (list of users)!

Whats going on here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have no problem with other browsers, I guess this is caused by [Chrome not adding a history entry after the redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9909850/1836314) (Chrome developers do not consider it to be a bug while the rest of the world seems to).